# How to check array element present in different class in java

Tags: java, class, oop, arraylist

I am writing a sample Playlist code in Java

1. I created Song class
2. I create Album Class which stores list of songs
3. Now i Have to add the song from an album into a playlist in Playlist class
4. For this i created a new AlbumsLists class which stores list of albums

Now while adding a song to playlist. How can i check if the song is present in the album , and whether the album is present in the list of albums stored in AlbumsLists

I am confused how to check
presence of an Album from a different class Because I cannot add
arraylist of albums in Playlist class.

**Song Class**

```
public class Song {
private String songTitle;
private int duration;

public Song(String songTitle, int duration) {
    this.songTitle = songTitle;
    this.duration = duration;
}

public String getSongTitle() {
    return songTitle;
}

public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("Song: " + songTitle + " Duration: " + duration);
}
public static Song newSong(String songTitle,int duration){
    return new Song(songTitle, duration);
}
}
```

**Album Class**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class Album 
{
    private String albumName;
    private ArrayList<Song> songsInAlbum = new ArrayList<>();

public Album(String albumName) {
    this.albumName = albumName;
}

public String getAlbumName() {
    return albumName;
}
public void addSong(String songName,int duration){
    songsInAlbum.add(Song.newSong(songName,duration));
}

public void displaySongsInAlbum()
{
    for(Song song: songsInAlbum) System.out.println(song);
}

public ArrayList<Song> getSongsList() {
    return songsInAlbum;
}
public static Album newAlbum(String albumName){
    return new Album(albumName);
}}
```

**AlbumsList Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AlbumsList {
    private ArrayList<Album> albumsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public AlbumsList(String album) {
        this.albumsList.add(Album.newAlbum(album));
    }
    public void addAlbum (String album){
        this.albumsList.add(Album.newAlbum(album));
    }
}
```

**Playlist Class**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class PlayList {
    private String playlistName;
    private LinkedList<Song> songsInPlaylist = new LinkedList<>();

    public PlayList(String playlistName) {
        this.playlistName = playlistName;
    }

    public void addSong(String Album,String song){
    /********************************
     *******************************************
     How to access AlbumLists from AlbumLists Class
     *******************************************
     *******************************************/
  
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing as your Song constructor is public, it's weird to add a static newSong method. remove that, and just use the constructor. You can't access anything from AlbumLists class, since in order to do this, you'll need to instantiate this class, and have access to this instance, but as far as I can tell, you never even use this class.

Comment: Yes, I haven't used. I am confused where to use...

Comment: you'll need to use it where you need it, but since that 'albumlist' only contains a list of Albums, which in turn only contain a single String, I don't see any use for any of those classes, personally

Comment: edit to my previous comment, I re-checked, you have a list of songs there as well, I just didn't spot it at the constructor. It would be best to have it in the constructor, not in a setter. after all, chances are small once the cd is created, the tracks on it will alter. But, since you already pass the album name and the song as parameters to the addSong method, why do you need to access the AlbumList there? to just get what you already provide by parameter?

Comment: I need to access to AlbumList because i have to add the song to the playlist only if the song is present in the list of albums

Comment: If the song is not a part of any album it cannot be added to the playlist

Comment: That's a bad design. It should only be possible to choose existing songs in the first place. But, if you need it this way, since AlbumList will be needed in such a way, it might be better to make it's members static. Fill it with albums at the start of your application, and just call a check in that addSong method